# Communication between terminal and issuer - EMV Transaction

Tags: terminal, emv

I am working on EMV technology and looking for the communication ( Request/Response) between terminal and issuer for authorization / online pin checking.

I know Offline data authentication check on terminal only and then terminal send data to issuer. I wonder **what data need to send for authorization process**.

I know little bit about DE elements ( like DE-55 element - contain data like Amount,Authorised(Numeric) ,Amount,Other(Numeric),ApplicationCryptogram(AC)).

Could anybody give me a link/documnent where I can see what and how communication in **what format** happening between Terminal and issuer for authorization (cryptogram validation) , Online PIN checking , CVV validation
and all.

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terminal communicates only with the acquirer. The communication between terminal and acquirer is determined by acquirer host system like Compass+, OpenWay, other and specific implementation you can ask your host provider (easier to ask the Bank for which the terminal will be the point of sale ). In common this all protocols are based on ISO8583, so you could read there. Also some information you can find at [EMV Book 4](https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223), 12 Acquirer Interface.

EMV Book 4:

> An authorisation message shall be used when transactions are batch
>   data captured. A financial transaction message shall be used when
>   online data capture is performed by the acquirer. An offline advice
>   shall be conveyed within batch data capture when supported. An online
>   advice or a reversal message shall be transmitted real-time, similarly
>   to an authorisation or financial transaction message.

Comment: I agree with Alexander. There are hundreds of protocols implemented between terminals and Acquirer/Merchant service providers. Behind are card-scheme related network interfaces, mostly based on ISO 8583. Here are some references to the core ISO 8583-like specifications used by Card Payment System associations - http://blog.iso8583.info/2016/02/iso-8583-like-specifications-used-by.html

Comment: @Alexandar , You wrote - Offline messages sent to the host sequentially in batch through "Authorisation Request" (if I'm not mistakеn).  could you explain this please??  apart from offline authentication (done at terminal)   and cryptogram validation (done at acquirer)  , there are CVV validation and Pin validation - if profile is online pin,  these two validation generally done by Bank - Issuer , Let me correct if I am wrong with my words. here acquirer send request to Issuer -bank for these two validation and if yes , use same ISO 8583 standard.

Comment: @Arjun About offline, when the terminal perform offline transaction it should send information  about transaction to Issuer(through Acquirer) at some time but not immediately. For example the terminal collects offline transactions data during the day and at the end of the day send all this collected data to the host. For detail look at the acquirer host implementation. Cryptogram validation done at the issuer too.
You're almost right, in general acquirer send request to the payment network, and payment network send request to Issuer. And back the other way around.

Comment: @AlexanderVgn Got it!!! , as per my knowledge, 1 - crytogram validation (ARQC) , 2 - online pin validation , 3 - CVV validation 4 - other card data need to validate by acquirer/issuer so the same sent to issuer/acquirer with in ISO8583 message ( found iso8583 message contain various card values) for validation/checking. I wonder what data sent to acquirer/issuer and who validate it ??? Is all require sent in one go or multiple iso8583 message send? too many questions.. you brief answer would help to understand terminal to Acquirer/issuer complete flow.

Comment: 1, 2, 3 require its corresponding keys master DES key, Pin verification key and card verification keys which will be available only with issuer hence can  be verified only with the issuer( acquirer stand-in is another case. you can ignore it for the time being).

a clear description on what you are asked to do will help people giving you clearer info.

Comment: @libadarsh.so.1.0.1 if acquirer and issuer is not a same entry then could you define what is the work of acquirer [ 1 ,2 and 3 is require some keys which will reside in issuer end, it is logical]  just receive the message from terminal and pass to Issuer or something else? Actually I am looking for the complete interaction of a transaction in respect to terminal - acquirer and issuer.

Comment: If the acquirer the issuer and different they would have an interface between them, which would be an iso8583 interface.
Even in this case the validations done by the acquirer are very less( keys 1, 2 3 not required).
It will get the data from the terminal, [processing], send to issuer through iso8583 interface, receive the response from issuer, do logging and batch processing etc, send response back to terminal.

When you send to issuer, in the iso8583 message you will provide all the data fields which I had said in my earlier post. This includes transaction + emv data fields.

Comment: Issuer responds to you in iso8583 message and data element 39 will tell you the fate of your transaction.

By 'processing' I mean something like below,
You may have multiple issuer. Decide to whoth the transaction to be routed to.
check the expiry date, card check digit etc and decline if it fails(in most cases this will get declined from terminal itself).
Translate the PIN Block from terminal PIN key to Zone PIN Key specific for the issuer

Answer (score 1):

```
Issuer does a couple of things
1. Validate the card, for example status, expiry date, PIN etc
2. Validate account, eg. account status, available funds, transaction type allowed on the account etc.
3. Validate the authenticity of the card by veriying the ARQC
4. Generate ARPC to let card know that the issuer is genuine.
5. Send post issuance operation using issuer scripts.

You may be mostly sending the data in ISO8583 in case you are using a POS or NDC+/D912 standards in case you are using ATMs.

PIN is sent as PIN Block encrypted under Terminal PIN key.
If host is the issuer it can do HSM command DC and verify the PIN. See the HSM documentation for the format and expected data.

CVV is a part of the track and verification happens with HSM command CY. Expiry date is available from track. Service code is also available but make sure it is the service code for iCVV.

Now considering the above requirements, I can say the following data are required to be sent to host.
Message type
PAN
Pcode
Amount
Local date and Time
Trace
expiry data (not mandatory in case you are sending track data)
POS entry code
PAN Sequence number
Track2
terminal id
Merchant ID
Acquirer Currency Code
Chip Data which includes
    All tags used in CDOL1( this would be sufficient for your HSM command KQ/KX)
    ARQ Cryptogram
PIN block in case online PIN is selected CVM
```

Try with this and let me know in case anything more is required.

Comment: Is all require data sent to Issuer/Acquirer in one go or multiple ISO8583 message sent? what data validate by acquirer and what by Issuer? I think pin check and cvv is validate by issuer end... could you tell, Is there are any defined task for Acquirer and issuer separately that will help to understand functionality of acquirer and issuer.

Comment: By terminology an acquier is who is acquiring a transaction and an issuer who issued  the card. 
If it is an ONUS transaction transaction, acquirer and issuer will be same entity. Let us say you try the bank's card on the same bank's terminal.
OFUS transactions means you are acquiring some other issuer banks cards.

Comment: Assuming you are using a POS as acquiring device,
you can send all the data i mentioned above in the same iso8583 message to the acquirer( which will be also the issuer when ONUS). you can go through iso8583 spec for the corresponding fields which will be more or less same in all implementations. Data element 55 is one among them, and will contain the EMV related data.

Comment: Usually the acquirer does not do much validation on the data except the data formats. Then it passes the data to issuer. Issuer does all the checks on the data you sent like PIN, CVV, card status, account status, EMV validations etc as I mentioned in my earlier post.

BTW, what is the part you are doing.